# How to turn off outgoing skype ringing sound?

Tags: sound, skype

I hate the sound skype plays when you try to call someone. It literally drives me crazy. Is there a way to turn off the sound? I'm using Xubuntu 12.10!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it from Options>>Notifications>>Outgoing Call Ring

[image]

Comment: Any answer for the new Skype?